# Eclipse duplicate Android code error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo to develop Android application. The problem I'm experiencing is that some given error messages are duplicated many times, preventing the code to be compiled even when the errors are fixed. For example, I wrote:

```
private OnClickListener foo = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I was reported *"Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration"* **7 times**. I fixed it and 6 error messages remained.

I closed Eclipse then restarted it, nothing changed. I guess it is a file to delete or something like this. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If your code is not too long, try post the entire code out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the problem, for those who may experience it someday.

1) I copied all the faulty (or reported as faulty but not really faulty) code to a text editor.

2) I deleted it from the java file and saved it. The errors disappeared.

3) I pasted back the code to the java file then saved it. **The errors did not re-appear**.

That's it.